# Besides indexing, how to speed up this query on 100m rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: r, postgresql, performance, indexing, survival-analysis

**Background**

First, let me know if this is more appropriate for the DBA StackExchange. Happy to move it there.

I've got a dataset, `db1_dummy` with ~100 million rows worth of car and motorcycle insurance claims that I'm prepping for statistical analysis. It's in PostgreSQL v13, which I have running on a local 64bit Windows machine and accessing through DataGrip. `db1_dummy` has ~15 variables, but for this question only 3 are relevant. Here's a toy version of the dataset:

```
+-------------------+------------+--+
|member_composite_id|service_date|id|
+-------------------+------------+--+
|eof81j4            |2010-01-12  |1 |
|eof81j4            |2010-06-03  |2 |
|eof81j4            |2011-01-06  |3 |
|eof81j4            |2011-05-21  |4 |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |5 |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |6 |
|j42roit            |2015-11-29  |7 |
|p8ur0fq            |2014-01-13  |8 |
|p8ur0fq            |2014-01-13  |9 |
|p8ur0fq            |2016-04-04  |10|
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |11|
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |12|
|vplhbun            |2019-08-15  |13|
|akj3vie            |2009-03-31  |14|
+-------------------+------------+--+
```

`id` is unique (a primary key), and as you can see `member_composite_id` identifies policyholders and can have multiple entries (an insurance policyholder can have multiple claims). `service_date` is just the date a policyholder's vehicle was serviced for an insurance claim.

I need to get the data into a certain format in order to run my analyses, all of which are regression-based implementations of survival analysis in `R` (Cox proportional hazards models with shared frailty, if anyone's interested). Three main things need to happen:

1. `service_date` needs to be converted into an integer counted up from 2009-01-01 -- days since January 1st, 2009, in other words. `service_date` needs to be renamed `service_date_2`.
2. A new column, `service_date_1`, needs to be created, and it needs to contain one of two things for each row: the cell should be 0 if that row is the first for that `member_composite_id`, or, if it isn't the first, it should contain the value of `service_date_2` for that `member_composite_id`'s previous row.
3. Since the interval (the difference) between `service_date_1` and `service_date_2` cannot equal zero, a small amount (0.1) should be subtracted from `service_date_1` in such cases.

That may sound confusing, so let me just show you. Here's what I need the dataset to look like:

```
+--+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
|id|member_composite_id|service_date_1|service_date_2|
+--+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
|1 |eof81j4            |0             |376           |
|2 |eof81j4            |376           |518           |
|3 |eof81j4            |518           |735           |
|4 |eof81j4            |735           |870           |
|5 |j42roit            |0             |2523          |
|6 |j42roit            |2522.9        |2523          |
|7 |j42roit            |2522.9        |2523          |
|8 |p8ur0fq            |0             |1838          |
|9 |p8ur0fq            |1837.9        |1838          |
|10|p8ur0fq            |1838          |2650          |
|11|vplhbun            |0             |3878          |
|12|vplhbun            |3877.9        |3878          |
|13|vplhbun            |3877.9        |3878          |
|14|akj3vie            |0             |89            |
+--+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The good news: I have a query that can do this -- indeed, this query spat out the output above. Here's the query:

```
CREATE TABLE db1_dummy_2 AS
SELECT
    d1.id
    , d1.member_composite_id
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN (COALESCE(MAX(d2.service_date)::TEXT,'') = '') THEN 0
            WHEN (MAX(d2.service_date) - '2009-01-01'::DATE = d1.service_date - '2009-01-01'::DATE) THEN d1.service_date - '2009-01-01'::DATE - 0.1
            ELSE MAX(d2.service_date) - '2009-01-01'::DATE
        END service_date_1
    , d1.service_date - '2009-01-01'::DATE service_date_2
FROM db1_dummy d1
LEFT JOIN db1_dummy d2
    ON d2.member_composite_id = d1.member_composite_id
    AND d2.service_date <= d1.service_date
    AND d2.id < d1.id
GROUP BY
    d1.id
    , d1.member_composite_id
    , d1.service_date
ORDER BY
    d1.id;
```

**The Problem**

The bad news is that while this query runs very speedily on the dummy dataset I've given you all here, it takes interminably long on the "real" dataset of ~100 million rows. I've waited as much as 9.5 hours for this thing to finish working, but have had zero luck.

My question is mainly: is there a faster way to do what I'm asking Postgres to do?

**What I've tried**

I'm not database genius by any means, so the best I've come up with here is to index the variables being used in the query:

```
create index index_member_comp_id on db1_dummy(member_composite_id)
```

And so on like that for `id`, too. But it doesn't seem to make a dent, time-wise. I'm not sure how to benchmark code in Postgres, but it's a bit of a moot point if I can't get the query to run after 10 hours. I've also thought of trimming some variables in the dataset (ones I won't need for analysis), but that only gets me down from ~15 columns to ~11.

I had outside help with the query above, but they're unsure (for now) about how to approach this issue, too. So I decided to see if the boffins on SO have any ideas. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

**EDIT**

Per Laurenz's request, here's the output for `EXPLAIN` on the version of the query I've given you here:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|GroupAggregate  (cost=2.98..3.72 rows=14 width=76)                                   |
|  Group Key: d1.id                                                                   |
|  ->  Sort  (cost=2.98..3.02 rows=14 width=44)                                       |
|        Sort Key: d1.id                                                              |
|        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1.32..2.72 rows=14 width=44)                       |
|              Hash Cond: (d1.member_composite_id = d2.member_composite_id)           |
|              Join Filter: ((d2.service_date <= d1.service_date) AND (d2.id < d1.id))|
|              ->  Seq Scan on db1_dummy d1  (cost=0.00..1.14 rows=14 width=40)       |
|              ->  Hash  (cost=1.14..1.14 rows=14 width=40)                           |
|                    ->  Seq Scan on db1_dummy d2  (cost=0.00..1.14 rows=14 width=40) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please share the `EXPLAIN` output for the query. Try to increase `work_mem` as much as you can.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` for the "dummy" version of the query, or the real thing? I'll post the dummy version. Re: `work_mem`, funny you mention it because someone else told me to do that and I got it to work (along with adjustments to `shared_buffers`, too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The real thing would be what is needed, because it shows the size and row count estimates. Are you saying that higher `work_mem` (which speeds up hash joins) solved the problem for you?

Comment: That's correct - someone I know had suggested it and I tried it out before seeing your comment. Until then, I was going to post my own answer about adjusting the `postgresql.conf` file -- but I'd be much happier if you add your own so I can give you credit. (Though I'll also say that @klin's answer below using window functions, which I didn't know about, worked brilliantly, and I just marked that one correct.) Up to you sir! PS: I'm going to insert `EXPLAIN` from the real thing anyway, because it may help some future reader!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is a real server killer(*). Use the window function `lag()`.

```
select 
    id, 
    member_composite_id, 
    case service_date_1 
        when service_date_2 then service_date_1- .1 
        else service_date_1 
    end as service_date_1,
    service_date_2
from (
    select
        id, 
        member_composite_id, 
        lag(service_date, 1, '2009-01-01') over w - '2009-01-01' as service_date_1,
        service_date - '2009-01-01' as service_date_2
    from db1_dummy
    window w as (partition by member_composite_id order by id)
    ) main_query
order by id
```

Create the index before running the query

```
create index on db1_dummy(member_composite_id, id)
```

Read in the docs:

- [3.5. Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)
- [9.22. Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)
- [4.2.8. Window Function Calls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

(*) *The query produces several additional records for each `member_composite_id`. In the worst case, this is half the Cartesian product. So before the server can group and calculate aggregates, it has to create some several hundred million rows. My laptop couldn't stand it, the server run out of memory on a table with a million rows. Self-joins always are suspicious, especially on large tables.*

Comment: This is really helpful and provides a lot of context I had no idea about -- particularly into how PostgreSQL processes things under the hood while it runs a query. In the few hours since I posted, a friend developed a sort of brute-force answer (which I'll post): I greatly increased some parameters in the `postgresql.conf` file, particularly the `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` parameters, to match my desktop machine's capabilities. Much of my 32gb of RAM was going unused while the query ran, for instance. And it worked! What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Of course, tuning database parameters can bring tangible results. Default Postgres parameters are prepared for an average PC from several years ago. If you have a strong machine, tuning can do wonders. Anyway, the query with `lag()` should be much faster than the one in the question. Try it.

Comment: This worked extremely well! EDIT: upon closer inspection it's not working consistently. Let me have a closer look and I'll get back to you with a summary.

Comment: Apologies for the delay here, @klin -- took me a couple days to give this the proper attention. You were correct: fiddling with `partition by member_composite_id order by id` was the right move. I replaced `order by id` with `order by service_date` and everything slotted into place in the results. Thanks so much again -- the query only takes 10 minutes to run on the whole dataset. Fantastic.

Comment: I'm glad that this is not the first time Postgres has had the opportunity to show its good side.